# slide show error cannot read style of undefined

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I found a w3 schools slideshow that seems to work half the time perfectly the other half it will give me an error that says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined at showDivs (slideshow.js:33) which is the x[slideIndex-1] part. I can't quite seem to figure out whats wrong.

HTML

```
<h2 class="w3-center"></h2>

<div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
  <img class="mybottom mySlides" src="pics/pic3.3.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mybottom mySlides" src="pics/pic3.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mybottom mySlides" src="pics/pic2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  <img class="mybottom mySlides" src="pics/pic4.jpg" style="width:100%">


  <button id="back" class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-left">&#10094;</button>
  <button id="forward" class="w3-button w3-black w3-display-right">&#10095;</button>
</div>
```

JS

```
  var slideIndex = 1;

  showDivs(slideIndex);

  function plusDivs(n) {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
  }

  function showDivs(n) {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}
    if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  }

  document.getElementById("back").addEventListener("click", function(){
    plusDivs(-1);
  });
  document.getElementById("forward").addEventListener("click", function(){
    plusDivs(1);
  });
```

Comment: Seems to be working for me. https://jsfiddle.net/bur72cdk/

Comment: yeah thats whats so weird. I'll refresh the page and it'll go from being fine, to giving that error and spewing all the individual slides in blocks down the website in a chain.

Comment: Are you sure you're not caching? Can you open it in a private mode on your browser? BTW which browser and version are you using?

Comment: So did a bunch of refreshes in private mode using Version 58.0.3029.81 (64-bit) Chrome, latest version and it also has the same problem. I notice that it happens most when I go through some of the slides when its working, then refresh the page. How would I stop cached data?

Comment: I just wanted to figure out if it was cached contents from a broken code from before, guess not. Do you have the JavaScript above or below the HTML? Does my JSFiddle breaks for you or that works fine?

Comment: its in a separate slideshow.js file linked to the bottom of the index.html with

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){}) at the top of the file

Comment: your jsfiddle works

Comment: I notice when I refresh the js fiddle I briefly see another picture below the slideshow